# svnrdump load fails because of property svn:author

Tags: svn

After I created the dump with svnrdump [mydump] and I want to load it into my repository [repourl] but I get this error message:

```
$ svnrdump load [repourl] < mydump
* Loaded revision 0.
svnrdump: E175008: While handling the 'svn:author' property on '/repos/xyz/!svn/txn/0-1':
svnrdump: E175008: Could not execute PROPPATCH.
```

I found something with keywords=Author but I'm not sure how to fix this correctly. The problem ist that after this error, the repository is locked by my user and I don't have any the permissions to unlock it, so I need to contact the administrator for each try.

Answer (score 0):

Use `svnadmin load` on the server computer instead of running the `svnrdump load` remotely.

Use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` in all cases when possible and minimize the use of `svnrdump`. The `svnadmin` tool accesses the repositories directly on disk (faster, does not depend on network or server), but `svnrdump` does this via the server (Apache or `svnserve`) and over network.

Please also make sure that you use up to date Subversion server and client tools.

Comment: The Problem is, I have no access to this server, so I need to call it remote.

Comment: @ms88-aut I’d rephrase this - you are trying to perform a repository administration task without admin’s privileges. Moreover, it seems that the server’s and svnrdump versions are very outdated.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask the admin about the version. Maybe this hint can help.